# Multiple values in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, string-matching

I am trying to save two values under one key for shared preferences in Android. The reason I want to do this is so that I can check a value of a string, and then replace it. 
For example, I want shared preference to have (key1,StringA,StringB). In my program, I want to check if a textView matches StringA, and if it does, replace it with StringB. Is there a way to do this with shared preferences? If so, how would I implement storing two stings under one key? If not, what is a better way I can do this? Thanks for any help.

So far, I check the textView value, and replace it with the shared preference like this...

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
        if (sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "").equals(stringname.getText())) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
            //I want to replace name(which is the textView) with StringB instead.
        }
        else {
            name.setText("Didn't Match");
        }
    }
```

So this is why I want to use two values that way the user can replace a specific TextView they desire into another string.

Comment: Add both the values as comma separated against the key. Then use string manipulations to get the values and do your logic.

Comment: So just add another value after the first with a comma? What kind of string manipulations? Would I put them into an array or..?

Comment: If you use a comma-separated string, be careful if any of the original strings contains commas. You must escape/unescape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because it will overwrite values if you use the same key anywhere.

But yes there is one alternative using which you can store multiple string values in a single preference key, each value separated by comma. Then you can use `convertStringToArray` to covert it into String array.

I wouldn't suggest you to do it because why should you write more code just for storing and manipulating values for a single key, instead straight way store values for different keys and make comparison with separate values straight way.

Comment: see the explanation above in josephus's answer for an explanation of why I need to do this. I think convertStringToArray might work, but how would I implement that using my code above?

Comment: @user3124083 ok got it. Try to implement stuffs with the alternative I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point, since you mentioned that you're doing it this way is just because

> The reason I want to do this is so that I can check a value of a
>   string, and then replace it.

You're imposing an unnecessary constraint on yourself. Why not just store the strings under different keys?

Comment: I'm using this in order to be able to add nicknames for specific strings. So say the service updates a name(A) to the textview, and the user has a nickname(B) for that person, instead of the original name(A) being posted to the textview, the nickname(B) is posted. @josephus

Comment: in that case, I recommend you add some logic in your key naming instead. for example you can have a prefix "nickname-" that you append to your normal key.

Comment: another way would be to use a different sharedpreference for storing nicknames. this way you can use the same key (so no constraint on string pattern)